# How to work with pdf files on back4app parse server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

i have been exploring back4app parse server. i am tiered of finding documentation for pdf files. I am trying to generate some pdf files on back4app parse server from its cloud function.i do not see any documentation for it. will some one guide me to find it and little enlightment will be highly appreciated.

edit:
pdf creator library out there ask for output path but in back4app we don't have early access to path. we create new file passing it data and then save it to object. how do we achieve the order.

Comment: Back4App cloud code is essentially a node.js app. You can install any npm module that handles pdf creation and use this module to create your pdf from cloud code. For example, I found this one that can be helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-creator-node

Comment: @DaviMacêdo we don't get explicit access to the files container storage. while we do `new parse.file(filename,{encoding/data}` that will return some response and we can save this created file to the object we want. i don't understand and find any documentation for different files like image,pdf,text or other, what kind of data and encoding/data we need to send for new file and what kind of encoding/data for saving this to some object.

Comment: It automatically identifies the file type by the extension but you can also pass the mime type if you want. It is not clear to me what you need to achieve. Do you want to create a pdf file on cloud code? or just store pdf files?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo yes, i want to create a pdf file on cloud and thing i don't understand is how do i save this file. first we need to create a file using new parse.file, what argument should i pass and for saving it to object what argument should i pass. thank you so much for responding.

Comment: @bikashamit Did you look at this guide?
https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#files

Comment: @TanzimChowdhury pdf library out there ask for path while creating it but on back4app, we do not have early access to the file. we create new file by giving data to it and later save it to object. how do we achieve this order?

Comment: It depends on the library you are using. If the library outputs a binary data, you can create then the file with `const file = new Parse.File("myfile.txt", bytes);`. If the library has only the option to save a file on local folder, you can do that as well. You can pass a file with something like: `myLib.save(path.resolve(__dirname,'./pdfs','my file.pdf'))`. Then you will have to open the file, read its bytes and create the save file in the same way I pointed out above to store on the cloud. Give it a try and share your progress so we can help on that.

Answer (score 0):

I some how managed get it done, thank you @Davi macedo. but there is some problem, i created pdf locally(root) cloud code,deleting it each time is envitable . this could be problem for more requests.
can someone improve little bit. would be great.
Here is my code.

 I have used pdf-creator-node for creating pdf.

```
var pdf = require("pdf-creator-node");
var fs = require("fs")
var path = require('path')
const pdf2base64 = require('pdf-to-base64');
Parse.Cloud.define("pdf", async (req) => {
//creating pdf
// var html = fs.readFileSync("template.html", "utf8");
var html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'template.html'), {
encoding: 'utf-8' });
var options = {
    format: "A3",
    orientation: "portrait",
    border: "10mm",
    header: {
        height: "45mm",
        contents: '<div style="text-align: center;">Author: Shyam Hajare</div>'
    },
    footer: {
        height: "28mm",
        contents: {
            first: 'Cover page',
            2: 'Second page', // Any page number is working. 1-based index
            default: '<span style="color: #444;">{{page}}</span>/<span>{{pages}}</span>', // fallback value
            last: 'Last Page'
        }
    }
};
var users = [
    {
        name: "Shyam",
        age: "26",
    },
    {
        name: "Navjot",
        age: "26",
    },
    {
        name: "Vitthal",
        age: "26",
    },
];
var document = {
    html: html,
    data: {
        users: users,
    },
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './pdfs', 'my_file.pdf'),//using path is necessary
    type: "",
};
return pdf
    .create(document, options)
    .then((res) => {
       
        return pdf2base64(path.resolve(__dirname, "/usr/src/app/data/cloud      /pdfs/my_file.pdf")) //this path /usr/src/app/data/cloud/pdfs still mystery to me.
            .then(
                (response) => {
                   // console.log(response); //cGF0aC90by9maWxlLmpwZw==
                    const saveFiles = async () => {
                       //creating file
                        const parseFile = new Parse.File('pdfFile.pdf',{base64:response});
                       // console.log(parseFile)
                       //saving file
                        const responseFile = await parseFile.save();

                        const Document = Parse.Object.extend('Document');
                        const document = new Document();
                        //saving it to object.
                        document.set('document', responseFile);
                        await document.save();
                    }
                    saveFiles();
                }
            )
            .catch(
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error); //Exepection error....
                }
            )
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

});
```

Comment: The pdf file in root of cloud is overwritten every time that's good. should i go with it.